# Modeling relationships between 100+ variables

Tags: distributions, modeling, multivariate-analysis, outliers

I have been interested in DS/ML for a few years now and I have been able to build some relatively simple models actually performing pretty well. Now I have this idea in mind but I am not sure how to tackle it so I am seeking advice. I hope to find some suggestions of literature/starting points I should invest into - I am not looking for a complete, spoon feed answer.

My example; say, we have a dataset containing over 100 variables reflecting protein concentrations obtained from ground samples. It is known from literature, that, all these proteins (and their levels) are related with each other ('many-to-many'). Protein 1 might have a strong relationship with 2 and 83, but weak relationships with all the other proteins. Sometimes it happens that due to machine errors, wrong protein concentrations are measured. Therefore we would like to develop an outlier detection method.

My hypothesis would be that if we learn the relationship of all these variables with each other (model the distribution?) that we can find outliers. Also, I have read about "generative" models - and I can imagine that if we know the distribution/relationship of all variables; we should also be able to generate "artificial" ground concentrations, and also fill in missing values if a few are missing.

Could anybody give me suggestions/reads where I should start to tackle these kind of problems?

Comment: Gaussian mixture models, or one of their extensions, e.g. see [here](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~paul/book.html) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben Bolker! I will check them out, looks promising :)